# Netbeans fonts have distorted between CentOS 7.2 and 7.4

Tags: centos, gnome, fonts, graphics

I'm having problems with Netbeans (programming IDE, written using Swing) on CentOS 7.4. It worked fine on 7.2 but we upgraded some kernel modules.

Since then some of the fonts within my Netbeans have become problematic:

[image]

I have Google'd around and found people suggesting to add this to my Netbeans config file, netbeans_default_options:

```
-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
```

but that hasn't solved the problem.

Could someone help suggest a fix?

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme to Metal?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Issue of an Incompatibility of the Java Engine which is shipped with Netbeans with the Host Machine.

I fixed this by installing the OpenJDK Package from the Repository and configuring Netbeans to use the Local Java Engine in `netbeans.conf` with the Variable `netbeans_jdkhome`.

```
# pwd
/netbeans/installation/dir/etc
# vi netbeans.conf
#Commenting shipped Java Engine
#netbeans_jdkhome="/netbeans/installation/dir/bin/jre"
netbeans_jdkhome="/openjdk/installation/dir/jre"
```

The only Inconvenience is that this Procedure must be repeated on every Netbeans Update.

Answer (score 0):

Run this to launch NetBeans:

```
/netbeans/dir/bin/netbeans --laf Metal
```

Basically runs the metal look and feel theme